# Deployed application not launching

Tags: android, android-debug

I'm working on an application. Recently while deploying application into android phone, the eclipse shows that application is successfully installed in mobile, but I cannot see that application in mobile. But if I see in application management, then it shows that application. The eclipse shows following message.

[image]. Please help me on this. Because of this I cannot test application on mobile device. Thanks.

Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.Introduction"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.new2fbc.Our_Staff"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about__us" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.new2fbc.What_We_Believe"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_what__we__believe" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.new2fbc.About_Us"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about__us" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.Menus"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menus" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.events.Events"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_events" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.notepad.Sermon_Notes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sermon__notes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.notepad.EditNote"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_note" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.connect.Connect"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connect" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.connect.Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.donate.Donate"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_donate" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.bible.KJV_Bible"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kjv__bible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.bible.ChapterView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chapter_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.bible.New_Testament"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new__testament" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.Outreach"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_outreach" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.Mission"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mission" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.SundaySchool"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sunday_school" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ministry.fbcalvarado.WomenMinistry"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_women_ministry" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Pls can you post your manifest? Also is the app working in emulator?

Comment: @ArunAntony:  Nop. It is also not working on emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You donot have the launcher activity. Add the following in one of the Activity Declaration

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```